# Execute Websocket evrey 2 seconds?

Tags: python-3.x

import json
import websocket
import requests
import threading
import time

def on_message(ws,message):
json_message = json.loads(message)
price = json_message['p']
print (price)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/btcusdt@aggTrade",on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()

```
I want to get message evrey 2 seconds
```

Comment: you can use [sleep()](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-time-sleep) inside a loop that uses your websocket

Comment: Hey yosry, welcome to the site! This is not a question, please try and rephrase your post so that there is a clear question.

Comment: how to use loop inside websocket?

Comment: hi Alexandre i want to get message evrey 2 seconds not evrey milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

import json
import websocket

def on_message(ws,message):
json_message = json.loads(message)
price = json_message['p']
print (price)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/btcusdt@aggTrade",on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).